# Name for this specific type of function?

Tags: calculus, terminology, symmetric-polynomials

As the title says, I'm trying to find the basic name for this type of function or what it's similar to. This is the function (one exponent increases the other decreases):

x$^5$ + x$^4$y + x$^3$y$^2$ + x$^2$y$^3$ + xy$^4$ + y$^5$

I vaguely remember seeing this in IB Math but I can't remember what it was used in or what it was called.

Comment: Or maybe "complete homogeneous symmetric polynomial"